# Is there something similar to gather function in Excel or VBA?

Tags: r, tidyr

May seem strange to ask a question about excel/VBA, but the VBA community here is kinda flopped, so maybe is more likely to have answers among R users:

I have a problem that can be easily solved using Tidyr, but I'm obliged in this case to use Excel.

So, for example, I have:

```
library(tidyr)

Date <- seq(from = as.Date("2020/02/01"), by = "month", length.out = 6)

Col1 <- 1:6
Col2 <- 10:15
Col3 <- 9:14
Col4 <- 2:7
Col5 <- 3:8

df <- data.frame(Date, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
```

I want:

```
df_2 <- gather(df, "variables", "values", -1)

> df_2

      Date      variables  values
1  2020-02-01      Col1      1
2  2020-03-01      Col1      2
3  2020-04-01      Col1      3
4  2020-05-01      Col1      4
5  2020-06-01      Col1      5
6  2020-07-01      Col1      6
7  2020-02-01      Col2     10
8  2020-03-01      Col2     11
9  2020-04-01      Col2     12
10 2020-05-01      Col2     13
11 2020-06-01      Col2     14
12 2020-07-01      Col2     15
13 2020-02-01      Col3      9
14 2020-03-01      Col3     10
15 2020-04-01      Col3     11
16 2020-05-01      Col3     12
17 2020-06-01      Col3     13
18 2020-07-01      Col3     14
19 2020-02-01      Col4      2
20 2020-03-01      Col4      3
21 2020-04-01      Col4      4
22 2020-05-01      Col4      5
23 2020-06-01      Col4      6
24 2020-07-01      Col4      7
25 2020-02-01      Col5      3
26 2020-03-01      Col5      4
27 2020-04-01      Col5      5
28 2020-05-01      Col5      6
29 2020-06-01      Col5      7
30 2020-07-01      Col5      8
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a long time since I used VBA in earnest, but I don't think there is a direct function. You could either produse a temporary pivot table, or rewrite the gather function in vba.

Comment: In Excel there is an option to paste transform though not exactly gather.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-in-excel-for-mac-9c16dd55-ed1a-4aa2-8b74-b1b9211e2ede